# If $f$ is integrable, continuous and $\lim_{x \to \infty} f \ne 0$ then there exist a sequence $x_n$ such that $f(x_n)$ is unbounded

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

A typical exercise is to exhib a function that is integrable but which doesn’t tend to $0$ as $x \to \infty$. An example we always see is the function that has bigger and bigger picks but of smaller width.
Now one question we could ask is : is all the integrable functions that doesn’t tend to $0$ have the same shape as the one described above.

That’s why I was wondering if the following is true. Let $f: \mathbb{R^+} \to \mathbb{R}$ be an integrable function (ie. $\int_{R^+} \mid f \mid \in \mathbb{R}$) and such that :

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) \ne 0$$

Then does it mean there exist a stricly increasing sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ such that the sequence :

$$(f(x_n))_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \text{ is unbounded}$$ ?

Edit : There are plenty of trivial example when $f$ is not continuous (see the comments and Richard’s answer). That’s why I just want to restate the question and ask if this is true when $f$ is continuous ?

Comment: The indicator function of the set of positive rationals is integrable.

Comment: @drhab Here I am talking in « Riemann » sense not Lesbegue.

Comment: Then take the indicator function of the set of natural numbers.

Comment: Yes you are right. If I add the assumption « continuous » do you think that the result hold in this case ?

Comment: The condition $\int |f| < \infty$ is called an [absolutely integrable function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolutely_integrable_function). For example $f(x) = \sin(x^2)$ is integrable without being absolutely integrable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function $\mathbf1_{\mathbb N}$ is integrable and takes care of a counterexample if no continuity is demanded.

If continuity is demanded then for every $n\in\mathbb N$ a nonnegative continuous function $f_n$ can be constructed that takes maximum $1$ in $n$, is $0$ outside $(n-\frac12,n+\frac12)$ and satisfies $\int f_n(x)dx\leq n^{-2}$.

Then evidently the $\sum_nf_n$ is a counterexample.

Comment: That’s clever. Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

No.
Let $f$ be defined by $f(x)=1$ for $n<x<n+1/n^2$, for all integer $n\ge1$, and $0$ otherwise. Then $\int_\mathbb{R}f$ exists and is $\pi^2/6$, but no such sequence exists.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have an example if I add the assumption that $f$ is continuous ?

Comment: @Interestingproblems Doesn't help. It's easy to glue it together with straight lines connecting $0$ and $1$ where needed - making it continuous - without changing the integral much. You can even make it smooth but using a [bump function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function).

Comment: @Winther Yes, unfortunately... I know that if the function is uniformaly continuous and integrable then it tends to $0$, but this is a strong assumption. That’s why I would like a less stronger assumption on $f$ that allows me to have informations about the boundeness, the limit at $\infty$...

Comment: @Interestingproblems $f\geq 0$ and monotonely decreasing is another one. Counter-examples like this shows that you do need a strong assumption if you want to get boundedness, otherwise there is just too much freedom to construct counter-examples.